# Comparing two strings in which one starts with a zero

Tags: php

I wanted to check two strings with each other, one which starts with a zero and one without. But this seems to result in a true. An example:

```
if("098" == "98"){
   return true;
}
```

Can somebody explain why this statement results to true with PHP?

Comment: if you add === it implies strict checking and it should be false

Comment: Yes that works but I was wondering why == won't work. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple reason i can think of is that The operator == casts between two different types if they are different, while the === operator performs a 'typesafe comparison'. That means that it will only return true if both operands have the same type and the same value.

So from your example,

```
if("098" == "98"){
   //true
}
```

Also a couple of PHP functions also have parameters to imply strict checking. An example is `in_array`

Answer (score 1):

if you compare with `==`, php tries to compare them without respecting the type. So what actually happens, php converts the two numbers to an integer, and as 98 is equal to 98, `"098" == "98"` is also true.

The best way to avoid this is, use `===`, which compares also the type without any conversions.

```
if("098" === "98"){
    return true;
}
```